# Dozens of ssh-agents listed under top

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I noticed this morning that our server was running slow so I ran a Top command sorted by mem and found a few apache instances running nothing out of the ordinary but I noticed several pages worth of ssh-agents. Any idea what this could be from and how I could go about A, removing them, and B preventing this.

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail?

Answer (score 0):

The server is probably starting ssh-agents in .bashrc or the profile file.
You should only start the agent once.